# Extract multiple lines of text between two key words from shell command in powershell

Tags: regex, shell, parsing, powershell

I have  a shell command I'd like to extract data from using Powershell. The data I need will always sit between two key words and the number of lines captured can change.

The output can look something like this.

```
Sites:
System1: 
RPAs: OK
Volumes: 
  WARNING: Storage group DR_UCS_01-08 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_TX
  WARNING: Storage group DR_UCS_21-28 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_TX
  WARNING: Storage group DR_UCS_31-38 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_TX
Splitters: OK
System2: 
RPAs: OK
Volumes: 
  WARNING: Storage group MA_UCS_1 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_MA
  WARNING: Storage group MA_UCS_2 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_MA
  WARNING: Storage group MA_UCS_3 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_MA
Splitters: OK
WAN: OK
System: OK
```

I would like to capture and store into a variable (or text file if easier?) part of this data to be reused later in the script. For example, I would like to capture everything between System1: and System2: which would produce:

```
RPAs: OK
Volumes: 
  WARNING: Storage group DR_UCS_01-08 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_MA
  WARNING: Storage group DR_UCS_21-28 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_MA
  WARNING: Storage group DR_UCS_31-38 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_MA
Splitters: OK
```

I've been messing with different regex combinations with no success. I've had some moderate success with this code but it doesn't seem to be able to handle the warning lines and I also can't seem to get Out-File to work with it either, only Write-Host which does not help me much.

```
$RP = plink -l User -pw Password 192.168.1.100 "get_system_status summary=no" #extract from

$script = $RP

$in = $false

$script | %{
if ($_.Contains("System1"))
    { $in = $true }
elseif ($_.Contains("System2"))
    { $in = $false; }
elseif ($in)
    { Write-Host $_ }
}
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to take this script and use it to parse data from any shell command. I'm currently lost and almost ready to give up on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to join the text with newlines, then use -split with a multi-line regex:

```
$text = 
(@'
Sites:
System1: 
RPAs: OK
Volumes: 
  WARNING: Storage group DR_UCS_01-08 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_TX
  WARNING: Storage group DR_UCS_21-28 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_TX
  WARNING: Storage group DR_UCS_31-38 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_TX
Splitters: OK
System2: 
RPAs: OK
Volumes: 
  WARNING: Storage group MA_UCS_1 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_MA
  WARNING: Storage group MA_UCS_2 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_MA
  WARNING: Storage group MA_UCS_3 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_MA
Splitters: OK
WAN: OK
System: OK
'@).split("`n") |
foreach {$_.trim()} 

$text -join "`n" -split '(?ms)(?=^System\d+:\s*)' -match '^System\d+:'

System1:
RPAs: OK
Volumes:
WARNING: Storage group DR_UCS_01-08 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_TX
WARNING: Storage group DR_UCS_21-28 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_TX
WARNING: Storage group DR_UCS_31-38 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_TX
Splitters: OK

System2:
RPAs: OK
Volumes:
WARNING: Storage group MA_UCS_1 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_MA
WARNING: Storage group MA_UCS_2 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_MA
WARNING: Storage group MA_UCS_3 contains both replicated and unreplicated volumes. ; CS_MA
Splitters: OK
WAN: OK
System: OK
```

Edit: a more generic solution to just capturing the output between two specific keywords:

```
$regex = '(?ms)System1:(.+?)System2:'

$text = $text -join "`n"

$OutputText = 
[regex]::Matches($text,$regex) |
 foreach {$_.groups[1].value -split }
```

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer. Assuming my shell output is stored in $text, can you tell me the code to pull data between two keywords. It won't always be system1 and system2

Comment: Ok, I think I misuderstood the question.  Updated the answer with a more generic solution.

Comment: That looks like just what I'm looking for! Is it possible for me to store that output to a new string, such as $output.

Comment: Sure.  Just assign it to a variable (updated answer with example).  Just be aware that if there are multiple instance of the keywords in the text, the result will be an array of strings (one for each set of keywords).

Comment: One quick follow up (maybe should be a new question?). When I do Out-File to that variable I seem to loose all the formatting and it is all on 1 line. Is it possible to maintain the new lines?

Comment: Ha ha. Yeah, use my solution where I preserve newlines. :)

Comment: Ah, now that I'm understanding this solution I'm gathering this may not be possible since we combined all lines. Is that the case?

Comment: I can't reproduce that.  The original string array (from your application) is being joined with newlines ($text = $text -join "`n"), and the result will be a single string with embedded newlines.

Comment: Your application should produce an array of single line strings (there are no newlines in the original data to "preserve".  If you need the result back as a string array, just split it on the newlines (bearing in mind again that there may be more than one set of lines being captured and you'll have to split each set individually).

Comment: OK thanks. Just because I'm curious, when I output in Powershell the original format is in tact. Why is it that the format remains there but not when using out-file?

Comment: I can't explain that.  I tested the script with your posted data, and if I pipe $OutputText through out-file, I get multiple lines in the file.

Comment: You are right, it was just notepad reading it differently. All I had to do was change one line to this: `$text = $text -join "`r`n"`

Comment: @mjolinor can you please have a look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785186/specific-text-of-todays-date-from-txt-file-by-powershell

Comment: OK, I posted a possible solution to that question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
$result = ($text | Select-String 'System1:\s*\r\n((.*\r\n)*)\s*System2:' -AllMatches)
$result.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
```

Where $text is your original input. Note that you might have to adjust your line endings from \r\n to \n depending on your input. You may also have more than one match, I'm not sure from your sample.

The regex starts matching with `System1:\s*\r\n` which is System1 followed by any number of spaces, followed by a newline. It ends the match with the literal `System2:`. The inner middle, `.*\r\n`, matches all characters followed by a newline. The outer middle `(.*\r\n)*` says to repeatedly match that pattern. Finally that construct is grouped, `((.*\r\n)*)` so that all the matching lines can be extracted as the result.

Comment: This is returning an error: 
'code'Cannot index into a null array.
At line:6 char:1
+ $result.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray)

Comment: Have you confirmed your newline format? Inspect $result.Matches and $result.Matches[0]. I tested it with your sample.

Comment: I tried switching the \r\n to \n but still get the same error.

Comment: Would a picture of the shell output be more useful?

Comment: No. Whatever is in $text is not the same as your sample. I copied it into a text file 'input.txt', then read it in with '$text = gc -raw input.txt'. Is $text a string or an array of strings? If it's a string, does it have newlines in it?

Comment: $text gets it's information from a plink putty session with this command:                                                        $text = plink -l admin -pw password 192.168.1.100 "get_system_status summary=no"                                    The output I put is the same besides some indentation that didn't come up right. Here is a link with the exact output from the plink command.              http://txt.do/ovqq

Comment: Got it with other answer, new lines were being inserted notepad just didn't understand, resolved with `$text = $text -join "`r`n"`

Comment: Yeah, the last edit to the regex should have solved it, but I'm glad you have your solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to adapt this script for myself, i want to do the same but instead catch what's between  and  (note-file from kobo-reader). At last got it working and it looks like this:

```
$text = @"
<text>The deaths I see are frequently undignified; the dying very often have not accepted or understood their situation, the truth denied them by well-intentioned relatives and doctors. Their death has been stolen from them.
</text>
            </fragment>
        </target>
        <content>
                <text>It is indeed impossible to imagine our own death; and whenever we attempt to do so, we can perceive that we are in fact still present as </text>
"@
$regex = '(?ms)<text>(.+?)</text>'

#Test
$OutputText = [regex]::Matches($text,$regex) | 
foreach {$_.groups[1].value }
Write-Host $OutputText

#Output
[regex]::Matches($text,$regex) | 
foreach {$_.groups[1].value } |
Out-File c:\temp\kobo\example_out.txt -Encoding utf8
```