# specific text of today's date from txt file by powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a text file. Similar to this.

```
This is a sample data.
This is a sample data.
This is a sample data.
Sat Jun 06 08:17:01 2015
WARNING: Cannot delete file.
Error-101
Error-100
Error-102
This is a sample data.
This is a sample data.
Error-10666
This is a sample data.
Sat Jun 06 10:17:01 2015
File deleted.
This is a sample data.
This is a sample data.
Sat Jun 06 10:17:01 2015
File deleted.
Sat Jun 06 11:17:01 2015
WARNING: Cannot delete file.
Error-101
This is a sample data.
Sat Jun 06 18:17:01 2015
WARNING: Cannot delete file.
Error-101
This is a sample data.
```

This file contain one month data.
There could be multiple files like this in a directory. Script will need to check the file that modified today.

I want to get the **Error-???** (Entire line of Error-) value of today's date.
So far i have created this.

```
$cur_date1 = get-date -UFormat %c
$curdate = (get-date).ToString("ddMMyyyy")
ForEach ($system in (Get-Content D:\Script\system.txt)) {
        $dir = "\\$system\D$\Error\"
        $latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter error*.txt | where{$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("ddMMyyyy") -eq $date }

$files=$latest.name
Foreach($file in $files){
         $path= $dir+$file 

        $search =  Get-Content $path 

    $a = $search| if($_ -eq $curdate){

    Where-Object{$_.Contains("Error-") }


    }

      }

}
```

I can check the files created today.
I can get content of entire file.
I can search the error- string but i am not able to search for current date.

Can anybody advise me on this?

Thanks.

If any changes need to be done in title or discription then please do so.
Thanks for your time.

**Update**

Just to inform you my system datetime format is as follows.
**dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you parse `error*.txt` file, you can save last seen date in a variable. So, when you encounter `Error-*` record, you will know to what date it related to.

```
$Today=[datetime]::Today
Get-Content D:\Script\system.txt|
ForEach-Object {
    $System=$_
    Get-ChildItem -Path "filesystem::\\$System\D$\Error" -Filter error*.txt|
    # filesystem:: allows code to work, even if current provider is not a filesystem provider.
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.Date-eq$Today}|
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.PSPath|
        ForEach-Object {
            $ParseDate=New-Object datetime
            $LastSeenDate=$null
        } {
            if([datetime]::TryParseExact($_,'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy',[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture,'None',[ref]$ParseDate)){
                $LastSeenDate=$ParseDate
            }
            if($_.StartsWith('Error-')){
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Error=$_
                    Date=$LastSeenDate
                    System=$System
                }
            }
        }
    }
}|
Where-Object {$_.Date.Date-eq$Today}
```

Comment: Your answer worked for me. I wil test one answer and after that i will marked one of them as answer. I am really thankful for your help.

Comment: Is it possible to print system name as well from system.txt (you have used $_)?

Comment: Error while running the script. Get-ChildItem : Cannot evaluate parameter 'Path' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.

Comment: @404 I remove `{` and `}` from `Get-ChildItem -Path`.

Comment: Perfect it worked. What was the issue. Can you explain.

Comment: @404 You can use script block for `-Path` parameter only if `Get-ChildItem` accept pipeline input: `$input|Get-ChildItem -Path {do something with input}`. This invoke script block for every input element and pass result to `-Path` parameter. As error says: *A script block cannot be evaluated without input.* So, when you does not have an input, then you have to pass value (not a script block) to `-Path` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can try converting each line to a datetime.  That's not a standard date format, however, so `[datetime]::TryParse()` isn't likely to work.  That means you'll need to use [`[datetime]::TryParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx), which is moderately more irritating because you have to give it a provider and a style, even though you're probably not using either.

```
$dateString = 'Sat Jun 06 08:17:01 2015';

[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]$provider = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture;
[System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]$style = [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None;

$format = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy";
[ref]$parsedDate = get-date;
[DateTime]::TryParseExact($dateString, $format, $provider, $style, $parsedDate);
$parsedDate.Value;
```

A key thing to note is that both `TryParse()` and `TryParseExact()` don't return values; they return True when the parsing is successful, and False when it fails.  In order to pass the result, you pass a variable by reference and the function modifies the referenced variable.  `$parsedDate.Value` is where the actual datetime value is because `$parsedDate` itself is a reference (pointer).

If the function fails and returns false, `$parsedDate` will have a value of `[datetime]::MinValue` (Jan 1, 0001).

Comment: Can you provide us some working code on this. I am not getting it.

Answer (score 2):

`$curdate` is a string with the format `ddMMyyyy`, whereas the string in the log file containing the date is in the format `ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy`, which I assume to be the current locale, hence your use of `Get-Date -UFormat %c`.

Therefore, your `if($_ -eq $curdate)` statement won't work.

`if($_ -eq $cur_date1)` *will* return true if the timestamp contained in `$_` represents the exact second your script starts running, but the subsequent `Where-Object` statement won't evaluate to `$true` (since `$_` is currently referring to the line with the date, not the error) and even if it did, wouldn't return anything (you haven't piped anything to `Where-Object` or specified an `InputObject` parameter argument)

As a general rule, for date comparison, don't use a string representation, use the `Date` property of the datetime objects you are comparing.

Wrong/frail approach:

```
Get-ChildItem |Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("ddMMyyyy") -eq $datestring }
```

Safe approach:

```
$today = (Get-Date).Date
Get-ChildItem |Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq $today }
```

---

If you want to extract the preceding date of an error message, the easiest way is to use `Select-String` with the `Context` parameter:

```
Select-String -Path C:\samplefile.log -Pattern "^Error" -Context 2 | Select-Object -First 1

  C:\samplefile.log:4:Sat Jun 06 08:17:01 2015
  C:\samplefile.log:5:WARNING: Cannot delete file.
> C:\samplefile.log:6:Error-101
  C:\samplefile.log:7:This is a sample data.
  C:\samplefile.log:8:This is a sample data.
```

You can then use the output data from `Select-String` to grab and compare the date:

```
$Today  = (Get-Date).Date
$Format = 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy'
Select-String -Path C:\samplefile.log -Pattern '^Error' -Context 2 | Where-Object {
    [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Context.PreContext[0],$Format,$null).Date -eq $Today
} | Select-Object @{Name="Error";Expression={$_.Line}},@{Name="Date";Expression={[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Context.PreContext[0],$Format,$null).ToString("ddMMyyyy")}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I will give it a try

Comment: I tested your script and it is parsing the value but one question i have it is giving me only single error. If there are multiple errors then it is not giving me the output for all the errors.

Comment: Be sure to not use the `Select-Object -First 1` statement, it was just to show you the output of **1** match with Context

Comment: If I use `$Today = (Get-Date 06/06/2015).Date` and your sample data I get 3 objects back (all with the value `Error-101` in the `Error` property)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but my concern is there could be multiple ERROR- under date. Your script is giving output for 1st match only or 1 can say 1 line only. e.g. Sat Jun 06 08:17:01 2015
WARNING: Cannot delete file.
Error-101
Error-102
This is a sample data. your code is not working properly in this case.

Comment: In above sample when i run your script it is giving me this error. Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:2 char:5

Answer (score 1):

I got pinged to the question, so here's my take on a solution:

```
#Create test file from posted data:
(@'
This is a sample data.
This is a sample data.
This is a sample data.
Sat Jun 06 08:17:01 2015
WARNING: Cannot delete file.
Error-101
Error-100
Error-102
This is a sample data.
This is a sample data.
Error-10666
This is a sample data.
Sat Jun 06 10:17:01 2015
File deleted.
This is a sample data.
This is a sample data.
Sat Jun 06 10:17:01 2015
File deleted.
Sat Jun 06 11:17:01 2015
WARNING: Cannot delete file.
Error-101
This is a sample data.
Sat Jun 06 18:17:01 2015
WARNING: Cannot delete file.
Error-101
This is a sample data.
'@).split("`n") |
#where { -notmatch '^#'} |
foreach {$_.trim()} |sc testfile.txt

#Proxy function for testing
function get-date {[datetime]'06/06/2015 18:17:01'} 

#Actual solution code follows:

$DateSearch = (get-date).ToString('MMM dd [0-9:]+ yyyy(.+)')
$DateSearch = '(?ms)' + $DateSearch

if ((Get-Content testfile.txt -Raw) -match  $DateSearch)
{ $Matches[1].Split("`n") -like 'Error*' }

#remove the proxy function:
 remove-item function:get-date

Error-101
Error-100
Error-102
Error-10666
Error-101
Error-101
```

This uses the `[datetime] tostring()` method to help create a regex to search for today's date in the file. Then it captures everything from that point to the end of the file, splits it at the newlines and filters out everything except the Error records.

Ignore that proxy function for get-date.  That's just there to get the script to work with the test data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will give it a try.