# Converting other zone date time format to local date-time format in PowerShell

Tags: date, powershell, datetime, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to perform date-time comparison.

Datetime in log file- **Tue Aug  4 17:05:41 2015**

Local system date time from get-date command -

**6. elokuuta 2015 10:18:47**

It's 6 Aug 2015 10:18:47 after I translated it on Google Translate.

How do I convert this date/time format, so I can perform comparison?

I tried multiple things and options, but no luck.

My script so far:

```
# To get today's date
$Today=[datetime]::Today
# Output is 6. elokuuta 2015 0:00:00

$log_date = "Tue Aug  4 17:05:41 2015"
```

I read somewhere that by using `new-object system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo`
it can be achieved, but I don't know how to change the current date-time with this. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730960.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[DateTime]` objects do not have a format. It just a number of `ticks` (0.0000001 second) passed since some point in time (01/01/0001 00:00:00.0000000). The format is only needed to save a `[DateTime]` object as a string or to display it to the user, since `635744160000000000 ticks` is not really understandable to a user.

All you need is to parse the string to get a `[DateTime]` object:

```
$log_date = [datetime]::ParseExact('Tue Aug  4 17:05:41 2015','ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy',[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture,'AllowInnerWhite')
```

Now as you have two `[DateTime]` objects you can compare them:

```
$Today -eq $log_date
$Today -lt $log_date
$Today -gt $log_date
```

Or find a difference between them:

```
$Today - $log_date
```

Comment: Can you advise how can i change ([datetime]::TryParseExact($_,'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy',[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture,'None',[ref]$ParseDate)) to above format. If you remember this code.

Comment: @404 `'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy'` -> `'ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy'`, `'None'` -> `'AllowInnerWhite'`.

Comment: when i use above code with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785186/specific-text-of-todays-date-from-txt-file-by-powershell/31808341#31808341. I am getting error "unable to find type [cultureinfo]: make sure that the assembly containing this tyle is loaded"

Comment: @404 Are you sure, you are not misspelling anything? And possible that in PS v2 you have to use full type name `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]`. I does not use v2 for very long, so can not say it for sure.

Comment: I checked that its PS v2. :( Not sure how to add it on v2. Need to search on google.

Comment: For PS V2 -  
$log_date = [datetime]::ParseExact('Tue Aug 4 17:05:41 2015','ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy',[globalization.cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture,'AllowInnerWhite')